# Database data appears in single line

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm only getting started with PHP and I have this problem that the data that I wish to display inside a html table from my phpmyadmin database appears in a single row rather than in multiple rows
 [attached screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PztR.png)

Here's the code:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=iwp_proj", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

$query = "SELECT * FROM `blog`";

$sql = $conn->prepare($query) ; 

$sql->execute();

$q = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>


<div align='center' style="background-color: white; opacity: 0.9">
<h1>REVIEWS</h1>

<table align='center' border='2' style=" border-collapse: collapse; bordercolor=#272121">
<thead align='center'>
<tr align='center'>
<th>Destination</th>
<th>Rating</th>
<th>Date of Journey</th>
<th>Comments</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>

<?php foreach($q as $row){ ?>
<td><?php echo ($row['dest']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['rating']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['bdate']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['content']); ?></td>
<?php } ?>


</tr>
<br>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**If I use the following code then nothing appears at all**

```
<?php while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
<?php foreach($q as $row){ ?>
<td><?php echo ($row['dest']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['rating']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['bdate']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['content']); ?></td>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<tr>` creates a new table row. Move both the opening and closing tags inside of your foreach loop

Comment: The `tr` should be inside the `foreach` loop

Comment: That fixed it, thankyou so much!

Comment: Also headsup. phpmyadmin is not a database. Its just a GUI web-based tool

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you're iterating over "td" elements only, instead of doing it on the "tr" elements. The line which contains the *forEach* method should be extracted from its current scope. An example follows:

```
<?php foreach($q as $row){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo ($row['dest']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($row['rating']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($row['bdate']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($row['content']); ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```